# Format spaces in dynamic variable to hyphens in return function in google map

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to format and replace the spaces in the output of **+marker.title+** and change them to hypens (-) for opening a modal dynamically. For example **San Diego** converted to **San-Diego**. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Not sure how much code you need to see but here is the entire loop. Thanks.

```
    $count = count($output);
            $i=1;
            echo 'var locations = [';
                foreach($output as $o) {
                    if ($i == $count) { $c = ''; } else { $c = ','; } 
                    echo json_encode($o) . $c;
                    $i++; 
                } 
            echo '];';
        ?>
        var marker, i;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.close();
        });

     for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
       markericon = (locations[i][7] == 'undefined') ? '' : locations[i][7];

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon: markericon,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][5], locations[i][6]),
            map: map,
            title: locations[i][0],
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {

            return function() {

                $('#'+marker.title+'').modal('show');

            }

        })(marker, i));
```

Comment: You forgot to write the programming language of your question.

Comment: I've attempted to add a tag for the language, based on my best guess on what it appears to be + the libraries used. Please correct this if I've made a mistake.

Comment: Yes apologizes Javascript and php. Thank you very much for updating my question. It's the first question I've posted on here. I'll get better at it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you would like to modify this line of the JavaScript code

```
$('#'+marker.title+'').modal('show');
```

In order to replace empty spaces with `-` you should use [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function in conjunction with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for empty string `/\s/`. So, your code should be changed to

```
 ('#'+marker.title.replace(/\s/ig, "-")+'').modal('show');
```

Proof of concept:

```js
var title = "San Diego";
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = title.replace(/\s/ig, "-");
```

```html
<div id="result">
</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much.